# Out-of-class definition of a static member of a variadic template class with non-type parameter pack dependent on a containing class's parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates, static, variadic-templates, non-type

For the following code:

```
template<class... Parameter> struct Outer
{
    template<Parameter... Value> struct Inner
    {
        static bool Member;
    };
};

template<class... Parameter>
template<Parameter... Value>
bool Outer<Parameter...>::Inner<Value...>::Member = true;

int main()
{
    Outer<int>::Inner<0>::Member = false;
    return 0;
}
```

GCC 7.3.0 reports:

```
error: expansion pattern 'Value' contains no argument packs
 bool Outer<Parameter...>::Inner<Value...>::Member = true;
```

and Visual Studio 16.7.2, simlarly, about the same `Value` parameter pack:

```
error C3546: '...': there are no parameter packs available to expand
```

Both compilers succeed, if in the same code `Parameter` is not a parameter pack, or `Value` is not dependent on `Parameter`.

Why are those errors occurring? Does this case require some special syntax?

I know that since `c++17` it can be solved by defining the member inside the class with the `inline` keyword. However I would prefer my code to be compatible with `c++11`, if it's possible.

Comment: Suggestion: `Outer<Parameter...>::template Inner<Value...>`?

Comment: @Quentin No, not working either.

Comment: that's crazy, I tried some forms and I got "fatal error C1001: Internal compiler error.", honestly speaking I never seen this before.

Comment: I passed the compile using Clang 10.0.0, I think this is somehow related to compiler implementation, maybe another undefined behavior trap?

Comment: @ravenisadesk Yeah, I think UB is possible. clang trunk doesn't accept this.